# For loop in MATLAB for vectors

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I run the following code and expect to get a vector IB, I do get a vector but all of whose elements are same I don't know what the problem is with this code?

```
function IB = ibtest(VCC)
    RL = [1000, 10000, 200000, 400000, 600000, 800000, 1000000];
    RB = 22000;
    RP = 50;
    R = 470;
    B = 300;
    i = 0;
    for t = 1:length(RL)
        i = i+1;
        IB(i) = ((VCC - 2.1)*(RL(i) + RP)) / ( (RL(i) * RP) + (RB*(RL(i) + RP)) + (301 * 470 * (RL(i) + RP)) );
    end
    IB
end
```

Comment: Could you replace your i's with t's

Comment: Try `format long`. The `IB` values could be actually different. With `format long` try `IB(2)-IB(1)`.

Comment: Problem solved with format long, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code. You should get equal numbers as you increase numerator and denominator by the same fraction every iteration. Try running this code:

```
function IB = ibtest(VCC)
    RL = [1000, 10000, 200000, 400000, 600000, 800000, 1000000];
    RB = 22000;
    RP = 50;
    R = 470;
    B = 300;
    for t = 1:length(RL)
        num = ((VCC - 2.1)*(RL(t) + RP))
        denom = ( (RL(t) * RP) + (RB*(RL(t) + RP)) + (301 * 470 * (RL(t) + RP)) )
        IB(t) = num / denom
    end
end
```

I also don't know what you want to compute so if you don't get what you expect there must be something wrong with the formula.